# allow visit a page if only came from a specific page

Tags: php, redirect, request, uri

My case:

1. articlesubmitted.php - read the last article information from a specific username from the database.
2. addarticle.php - add article to database.

I want to do articlesubmitted.php accept visits ONLY from addarticle.php and if is possible to be readed just 1 time by the user which he submitted the article.

I found something with REQUEST_URI but can't make to work.

How can I do that? it is possible to made from .htaccess?

Comment: To make it easier to help you please let us know what exactly you did try and how didn't it work?

Comment: Tried with REQUEST_URI but I don't found nothing to set for it to accept visits only from a specific page.

Comment: Yes how did you try what code did you put where?

Comment: I think the only way to do that, is set a specify param to pass from that page and checkit before load the page.

Comment: Try a mix of `if` with `[HTTP_REFERER]`

Comment: @JohnSmith Have a look at my example below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following example with your present code:

HTML LINK (link_for_get_access.php)

```
<a href="get_access.php">GO HERE</a>
```

get_access.php

```
<?php

if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"example.com/link_for_get_access.php"))

{

echo "<h1>You have access.</h1>";

}
else
{

echo "<h1>Sorry, you don't have access.</h1>";

}

?>
```

Comment: This Works, also I added: if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { header("location: /"); }

Comment: @JohnSmith That's great John, happy to hear it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use cookies to do this. For example with $_SESSION:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Do this at the top of every page
$_SESSION['last_page'] = isset($_SESSION['current_page']) ? $_SESSION['current_page'] : NULL;
$_SESSION['current_page'] = 'this_page.php';

if($_SESSION['last_page'] !== 'addarticle.php')
   throw new ...

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the http servers rewriting module you can evaluate the `HTTP_REFERRER' that usually is contained inside any http request if the user resolves a link (clicks on a link) to load a url. When the specified referrer does *not* match one that is allowed you can redirect the request to wherever you want to. Operating on that level is *much* faster than doing things inside php. Note that this typically also blocks any requests not triggered the usual way by clicking a link.

The second requirement, to limit the request to only a single attempt is very hard to implement on server level. It is much easier to control it inside the user session just as others here pointed out.